# How can I merge a row group in Report Builder?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report

I am trying to merge all occurrences of a row group into 1 single row. The top is an example of what my report looks like and the bottom is what I want it to look like.

[image]

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: You'll need to show your report design, including the rowgroup setup, the expression you are currently using to populate the 'X' and finally some sample data from your dataset so we understand how your report is currently working. Usually this issue is having a details group, or row groups with expressions that don't aggregate.

Comment: You can use `Max(Fields!FoodType.Value)` to merge like you want it. But this **assumes**, that you have only one non-null record per row